# Folders not available under Windows anymore

Tags: windows, filesystems, hidden-file

Many of my folders in Windows disappeared out of the blue. For example C:\Program Files and C:\USERS are missing in Windows Explorer. Moreover, I can't start any of my usualprograms with the Start Button (such as Adobe Photoshop) as Windows complains the file can't be located. For a moment thought they have been deleted, however, within CMD I cann see them as hidden with

```
dir /a C:\
```

But in File Explorer (have to start it from comand line as otherwise it won't work), these folders are not there. Show hidden items under checking hidden items in File Explorer don't show them either.

I tried in CMD as admin,

```
attrib -H -S C:\*.* /S /D
```

But I get a lot of Access Denied errors.

I also tried index these through Indexing Options to no avail.

I checked the harddrive with CHKDSK /F and also through Window Explorer and Startup Check and all show there are no problems with the harddrive. Virus Scanner (Bitdefender) didn't find anything in a complete scan too.

There is also nothing I installed recently that would explain what is going on. Last install was Bitdefender but days ago. The problem started out of the blue when I tried to run Adobe Premiere and it displayed a message that it can't be found. I am at a loss here and am considering a blan format and reinstall Windows. Any references by googling show the usual stuff (unhide folders), index etc. but nothing has worked so far.

System info

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19043 N/A Build 19043
```

Comment: If the files were still there (hidden or not), you wouldn't be getting file not found errors.

Comment: Then I really wonder what the issue is. :/

Comment: have you scanned for malware or virus?